# How to login through webview and send data back to the native Android App

Tags: android, android-intent, authentication, webview

In my App, the user registration process if a bit complex. So I wanted to use web view and call the  webpage, once the registration is done, I would like the user to  be back on the Native app , Main screen activity .

How can I implement it , after registration a regID is generated , I want to send this regID back which will  tell my app the user is logged in and registered .

How can I send variables from web view to Native app ?

Comment: heyy u solved this problem?? i stuck in same problem..if u solved this problem just say me how to implement this.thanks in andvance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Javascript Interface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29), it allows you to communicate with a webview and your native app; It's quite easy to use.

I would advise you to rather try to find a normal, all-native solution first though :) 
Perhaps you can re-forumulate your question and get some help with that too, before resorting to obviously less quality options.